# how to remove type checking error in typescript + react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui, material-design

I am getting below error . can you please help me to resolve below error.
I am using react + typescript + Material UI . I am trying to customise button using below link
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#2-reusable-component

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cdn-g4c2r6?file=/src/btn.tsx

I created button like this

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button, { ButtonProps } from "@mui/material/Button";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

type MuiButtonVariants = {
  [props: string]: "contained" | "outlined" | "text" | "error";
};

interface DWButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  buttonType: string;
}

const StyledDPWButton = styled(Button)<DWButtonProps>(({ theme }) => {
  return {
    fontWeight: 700
  };
});

const ButtonVariantsMapper: MuiButtonVariants = {
  primary: "contained",
  secondary: "outlined",
  tertiary: "text",
  error: "error"
};

const DWButton = (props: DWButtonProps) => {
  const { buttonType, children } = props;

  return (
    <StyledDPWButton
      variant={ButtonVariantsMapper[buttonType!] || 'contained'}
      buttonType={buttonType}
    >
      {children}
    </StyledDPWButton>
  );
};

export default DWButton;

 <DWButton buttonType="primary">nnn</DWButton>
```

I am using button like this

[image]

```
  Type '"contained" | "outlined" | "text" | "error"' is not assignable to type '"contained" | "outlined" | "text" | undefined'.
          Type '"error"' is not assignable to type '"contained" | "outlined" | "text" | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variant props accepts only values from `'"contained" | "outlined" | "text" | undefined'`.

remove `error: "error"` from your ButtonVariantsMapper and it should work fine.